# Why do all antivirus flag all keygen, crack or hacks as a threat?

Tags: virus, malware, anti-virus

I've been using computer for 20 years and I've used many antivirus. And I have had many "cracking software" laying around on the various PCs that I have used. These include keygen, software cracks/patchers and game hacks (wallhacks, aimbots, multihacks and etc).

I notice that sooner or later, whatever antivirus program I am using flags those software as a threat (malware, virus, trojan and etc). Is it correct that all such software contain some kind of threat? Or all antivirus are designed to treat all such software as a *possible* threat?

Comment: Answers will be opinion-based. My opinion is Jo Public looking to crack office/photoshop/whatever is a prime target for a malware attack. If they're not willing to pay for licensed software, they're unlikely to care what the source of the tool is. And that's just my opinion.

Comment: @spikey_richie not entirely true. I think the answer here is: we simply don't know or can't say. Don't think that counts as an opinion. I agree with the rest though...

Comment: All security software actually doesn’t. The problem is there are only a couple truly separate companies.

Comment: Its just easier to treat them all as possible threats. Cracks/cheats/keygens/... are easy targets to fake and distribute viruses, trojans, ... instead. Searching google for a keygen will turn up thousands of websites serving 0 keygens but a load of viruses instead. Second, some of them have virus like traits or behaviour to circumvent antipiracy measures (dll hijacking, process hiding, ...). Last, the 'real' keygens, cracks and whatnot serve no legal existence anyway, so why bother investing time and money in researching them ? Just blanket flag them all.

Comment: Mostly its about what they Do to achieve their end. Binary Patching is a good example. generally speaking modern applications do not patch binaries, but instead ship a new version of the binary. Binary patching is often used to change an executables behavior invisibly, without updating the executables version. in the modern era, this is unusual, and generally represents that the patch was developed via reverse engineering, rather than by modifying the source code and recompiling.

Comment: They use to mark them as hack tools, Microsoft does not want these obviously. They are only a threat to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

When a program is coded in its native program language, the script cannot actually be executed by itself. It needs to be interpreted by a parser or compiled to an executable.

In order to distribute the program to others, you always compile the program to an executable. An executable however is not the scripted code in a shell, but it is a reconstructed set of instructions that the processor understands in order to do what you initially programmed.

Understanding this is important. When virusscanners create their threat detection, they will search read all executables. A virus will modify an executable and change some code so the virus itself will be run whenever the executable is run. The virusscanner will search for this virus by simply searching for a pattern. The virus may have 80 bytes of code, but 50 bytes of that code contain the harmful instructions so the virusscanner will scan for those 50 bytes.

This ensures that any modification to that virus to cloak itself, will still result in a detection in most cases. It can't change the dangarous code in itself or it would simply not work like that anymore.

Virusscanners have a huge database with all these patterns called virus definitions.

When a virusscanner finds a virus, it finds that pattern. It is possible this detection finds a false-positive, a match of generic code that has the same signature as a virus.

Because virusscanners don't like it when their paid software is cracked, it will mark any crack or keygen as unsafe to protect itself, but it is also possible that someone creates a crack and puts in a virus so that this person can later collect information about who uses their crack etc...

When it comes to knowing if keygens, cracks, hacks, etc... contain actual malicious code, I have no answer to it. It can be, and its possible it is not the case. It is often true that in order for a crack to work, it has to perform functions that viruses also do, which is why most cracks are seen as dangarous. Their tasks cannot be distinquished from viruses.

The same problem happens with real programs too. They may have operations in them that could be flagged as a virus. If that happens, the developers usually contact the virusscanner developers and get their program investigated so a better match is created, and the false positive won't happen in the future.

TL;DR: It does so because those cracks/keygens/etc contain a signature of the virus it detects. Whether or not it is real and why it detects that, can't be answered. Its different per usecase and per virusscanner.

Comment: In addition to signature detections, you have heuristics, that may classify programs that perform tasks like reading another processes memory, or performing a dll injection, or install by patching a binary as malicious. some of them may allow executables with verifyable signatures, or may not. no strict rule to it